# Unable to connect Firebird 3.0 embedded version

Tags: database, firebird, firebird-3.0

I have tried to connect to Firebird database file using IBExpert and Flamerobin always got this error "Unable to complete network request to localhost"

Is there any changes in Firebird 3.0 with embedded version, because I can connect to version 2.5.5 without any problem?

Comment: Which Firebird 3.0 files did you include in your project.

Comment: Please share connection string that you have used for  connect.

Answer (score 6):

I solved the problem and now it works great.

The problem happens if Firebird plugins folder is missing and need to put it in the root with exe file like this:

- exe file
- db file
- fbclient.dll
- plugins folder
- engine12.dll ( only this file needed from plugins folder )

To let Flamerobin work you need to put fbclient.dll and plugins folder in Flamerobin folder!

Comment: Can you provide a demo application for that, it will help me.